# InvalidCastException with replaced IFileOpenDialog

Tags: c#, com, com-interop, openfiledialog

**Objective**

I'm working to replace the system file open dialog ([IFileOpenDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/common-file-dialog)) with a custom dialog.
My current solution works great when the file open dialog is invoked by many external programs (e.g Word, VS, Edge...) but not when invoked from .NET.

**What I did**

- Created a COM component in C# with the same Guid as the system file open dialog, implementing the IFileOpenDialog interface
- Edited the registry with the (hopefully) proper keys to redirect the file open dialog to my custom dialog dll

**The issue**

Everything works fine (my custom dialog is shown) when the open file dialog is invoked using CoCreateInstance, e.g from a c++ program:

```cpp
hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, 
    IID_IFileOpenDialog, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pFileOpen));
```

But when I execute the following from c# I get an `System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from CustomOpenDialog.FilesOpenDialog to type FileOpenDialogRCW`.

```cs
var ofd = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
ofd.ShowDialog();
```

**Code details**

My C# DLL project contains the following:

- Definition of the relevant COM interfaces (just showing some of them below, most have been taken from the [Vanara library](https://github.com/dahall/vanara)).

```cs
[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
[ComImport, InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("42f85136-db7e-439c-85f1-e4075d135fc8")]
public interface IFileDialog : IModalWindow
{
    ...
}

[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
[ComImport, InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("d57c7288-d4ad-4768-be02-9d969532d960")]
public interface IFileOpenDialog : IFileDialog
{
    ...
}
```

- Class implementing the custom dialog

```cs
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("DC1C5A9C-E88A-4DDE-A5A1-60F82A20AEF7")]
[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class FilesOpenDialog : IFileOpenDialog, IFileDialogCustomize, IFileDialog, IFileDialog2, IModalWindow, ICustomQueryInterface
{
    ...
}
```

- I edited the registry by applying this reg file (generated with the help of RegAsm):

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CustomOpenDialog.FilesOpenDialog]
@="CustomOpenDialog.FilesOpenDialog"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CustomOpenDialog.FilesOpenDialog\CLSID]
@="{DC1C5A9C-E88A-4DDE-A5A1-60F82A20AEF7}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{DC1C5A9C-E88A-4DDE-A5A1-60F82A20AEF7}\Implemented Categories\{62C8FE65-4EBB-45E7-B440-6E39B2CDBF29}]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{DC1C5A9C-E88A-4DDE-A5A1-60F82A20AEF7}\ProgId]
@="CustomOpenDialog.FilesOpenDialog"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{DC1C5A9C-E88A-4DDE-A5A1-60F82A20AEF7}]
@="File Open Dialog"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{DC1C5A9C-E88A-4DDE-A5A1-60F82A20AEF7}\InProcServer32]
@="mscoree.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Both"
"Class"="CustomOpenDialog.FilesOpenDialog"
"Assembly"="CustomOpenDialog, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=02fdb5bc5db3ac4c"
"RuntimeVersion"="v4.0.30319"
"CodeBase"="file:///<PATH_TO_DLL_FILE>"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{DC1C5A9C-E88A-4DDE-A5A1-60F82A20AEF7}\InprocServer32\1.0.0.0]
"Class"="CustomOpenDialog.FilesOpenDialog"
"Assembly"="CustomOpenDialog, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=02fdb5bc5db3ac4c"
"RuntimeVersion"="v4.0.30319"
"CodeBase"="file:///<PATH_TO_DLL_FILE>"
```

Any clue about how to solve the issue?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Because your code is .NET, the calling code is .NET and both are running in process, so you end up with a full .NET to .NET execution path, COM being out of the loop, with 2 classes that cannot be cast one to another, kinda ironic. One solution would be to write an entry wrapper in C/C++ (or anything else but .NET), or an out-of-process COM server instead of inproc, to force COM proxying (not sure IFileDialog supports that...). Or Try to different registry ThreadingModel like "Free".

Comment: Thanks a lot @SimonMourier I had the feeling a rewrite in C++ was coming. (In case you were wondering, setting the ThreadingModel to "Free" or "Apartment" does not fix the issue)